# Why is Visible Property Missing in Windows Form Properties?

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility

The Title is self-explanatory. There are Many Forms in the Project i am working on. All the forms have "Visible" attribute in their properties , but only one form doesn't have the visible attribute. Any Idea?? I am trying to show up the form onClick of a button which is in other project of the same assembly. But, the form just shows up for a second and hides away.  So, i want to ensure that the form visible property is set to "True" in the Form properties, but the visible property is Missing for that specific form.

Comment: What is the class definition for your form? is this vb.net or c#?

Comment: Is that form of Type `Form`or is it a subclass?

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: [`Control.Visible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Sayse  Project is in C#.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé  Its of Type Form. Not any derived /subclass

Comment: Do you get an error if you use the property in code? What VS version do you use? Additionally: Did you restart the development environment? (I recently had some issues with VS2012 that were resolved after a software restart)

Comment: @RomanoZumbé I use VS2010. I did check by restarting VS, but that didn't fix the issue . i did try to set "Visible" to "True" at run-time. And it didn't fix the problem as well. But, no errors thrown whatsoever

Comment: Please just try to reimport the forms sourcecode files to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what was the problem but, the function which controlled the visibility of this form was being called in a thread. And,while experimenting it ....i removed the thread and just called the function. The form became visible, although the visible attribute is still missing in properties section of the Form.